# python-dev installed and Python.h in place, but error on include

Tags: python, c, header, include

I work on a u 18.04 and a third party tool (pymesh) that I use needs to include `Python.h`

I installed python-dev, python3-dev, libpython-dev and libpython3-dev.

`Python.h` is found in the folders: `/usr/include/Python/`, `/usr/include/Python3.6m/` and `/usr/include/Python3.6/`.

Still when I try to compile a minimal C-program:

```
#include<Python.h>
int main(){}
```

I get the error:

```
$ gcc test.c 
test.c:1:9: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include<Python.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I can fix this by making symbolic links to every header in one of those directories in, e.g., `/usr/local/include/` or by specifying the path in the `#include` statement, but is that the correct way of doing it?

Comment: try `#include <Python/Python.h>` similar to how you would `#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>` it's fine

Comment: Are you trying to compile pymesh or a custom program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `-I` [option of gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Directory-Options.html):

```
gcc -I /usr/local/include test.c
```

Comment: @steffen are you sure the 3rd part package doesn't have a method of re-generating the makefile (eg. cmake, automake, etc). It's pretty rare for projects to write makefiles without generation.

Comment: Do you have a config script where the location of python.h could be specified as an option?

Comment: Yep, regenerating the makefile is the way